# Insomnia API Convert Document to Collection

Tags: insomnia

On my local Insomnia client, I have a Design Document created falsely a while ago, which has hundreds of API requests I use frequently. It has environment variables set up for multiple folders.

As I don't need the Design/Test function as in Design Document, I wanted to convert these API requests into a Request Collection for quicker access (no need to click the "DEBUG" tab for the request, and cleaner export). Is there a way I can do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit `insomnia.Workspace.db` file in Application Data folder. There is a scope for each workspace set to either `collection` or `design`.

Full process described in this comment: https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/discussions/3833#discussioncomment-4671745